# I got a virus, never seen anything like this

Tags: malware

My computer is running Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit.

Not 100% sure what happened but I got a virus on my laptop. Never had an issue with this before and when I went to bed last night everything was working normal. I did a reboot before I went to bed and when I woke up this morning IE was open with a ton of tabs, I had 4 alerts from UAC and AVG had a message up about infected files. I was in a hurry to get to work so I only had a few minutes to investigate.

I kept clicking No to the UAC messages but they would never close so I finally clicked yes.

I tried to run MBAM but as soon as I click on the Start Menu, the focus is put on the search bar at the bottom and it just starts typing spaces and I can't click on anything else in the start menu. I can navigate to where the MBAM.exe file and when I run it the program never launches. I try to rename it and we are back to the computer injecting spaces in to whatever/wherever I try to type.

That's about all I know right now. I can't check anything cause I'm posting this from work. Have you ever seen anything like this or have an idea how I can start to remove it? I've never had a malware problem on this laptop before and I've had it a year and a half. I'm tempted to format/reinstall Win 7 Ultime because I just got a MSDN subscription :) But I'd like to have a crack and trying to get around this malware to see what I can do to rid the world of this mess.

Comment: Do any other executables (especially powerful tools, like `regedit.exe` and `cmd.exe`) run?

Comment: Well, I'm having problems getting to the .exe's because I can't type. Are those tools stored in C:\WINDOWS or C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32?

Comment: Have you tried the run dialog?

Comment: Can you get into task manager and perhaps run things from there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fastest/Best way to clean it up is to create a bootable AV scan disc, boot from it and scan the hard drive for the infection and remove it, when you reboot there may be some remnants of the infection, use MBAM to clean those up.

http://www.techmixer.com/free-bootable-antivirus-rescue-cds-download-list/

When you are clean be sure your OS is fully patched, this includes things like Flash Player, Firefox if you use it or any other browser besides IE. Also update any other Adobe products you may have installed. Update Java if it is installed.

1. Use Windows Updates to check for security patches.
2. Flash player  http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/
3. Java  http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/  if this shows you don't have Java installed you are OK, but if it shows a version number go to this page to see what the latest version is and install it.  http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp

Comment: Still unsure of how I got the virus but the Kaspersky Live CD from the techmixer.com link worked for me. The scan took about 4.5 hours.

Comment: Be sure to follow up with MBAM scan.

Answer (score 2):

Try booting up windows in [Safe Mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Start-your-computer-in-safe-mode). You should be able run your antivirus or anti-malware software from there.